# Migrate reporting services to new server (just services not database)

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, ssrs-2014

I have a database cluster of 2 nodes (eg IPs. 110, 120). I have evicted 110 node and now only 120 is active.

Reporting services are hosted on 110. Now I have installed reporting services on 120 as well.

I want to change the Reporting service URL in Dynamics AX Client from 110 to 120. Simply changing the url doesn't works. I'm unable to deploy reports, it throws this error:

> “The process cannot access the file '\AAA-BBB\C$\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting
>   Services\ReportServer\bin\DrillThroughCommon.dll' because it is being
>   used by another process.”

What steps should I follow for to change the url?

**EDIT:**

Reporting Services were installed on 120 as I checked.

I noticed that after uninstalling ax reporting services from 120, when I try to install it back, the setup doesn't asks for the AOS instance whereas when I installed it on a fresh server it asked me for the AOS instance. How can make it prompt me the AOS server on 120? Any file to delete?

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is you're missing the Reporting Extensions on `120`. It's a component from the ISO you need to install **on** the SRS machine.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/install-the-reporting-services-extensions

Also, to specify a reporting configuration, see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/create-a-new-microsoft-dynamics-ax-configuration

It could be you just need to stop the SSRS services and/or specify the config.

**EDIT** After rereading, it looks like you are using a shared path for your install somehow, so one of the SRS services is probably locking the file.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Couldn't resolve it yet. For a temporary fix installed reporting services on a new server. I editing one more thing in the question, can you check it.

Comment: @MYGz Have you just tried restarting the different servers? If the file is locked, something is locking it...likely reporting services.